# Android Full screen float window cannot touch

Tags: android

```
mWindowManager =(WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

wmParams.type =  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
wmParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
wmParams.flags =  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
wmParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
wmParams.x = 0;
wmParams.y = 0;
wmParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
wmParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

This is my float window in system window, but it cannot touch to other app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

your can change the flag of params

```
wmParams.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
```

Comment: thank you,but if set FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,the fioat window can not accept event....

Comment: touchable and untouchable contradict each other, you can split a big view to several small views, windowmanager add small views one by one with different params